# Network clients threads all calling SQL commands the same time

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I've a bunch of clients connected to a server. When the client sends data to the server it creates a thread to process the message.

```
        serverSocket.BeginAccept( new AsyncCallback( AcceptCallback ), null );

    //client.cs
    private void RecieveCallback( IAsyncResult ar )
    {
        Socket socket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        try
        {
            int recieved = socket.EndReceive( ar );

            if ( recieved <= 0 )
            {
                CloseClient( index );
            }
            else
            {
                byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[recieved];
                Array.Copy( buffer, dataBuffer, recieved );
                ServerHandleNetworkData.HandleNetworkInformation( index         //ServerTCP.cs has an static array of clients
                                                                                //index is this clients position in the array
                                                                , dataBuffer
                                                                );
                socket.BeginReceive( buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback( RecieveCallback ), socket );
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "[Client::RecieveCallBack] " + e.Message, index );
            CloseClient( index );
        }
    }
```

These threads call static methods that handle network information. They also call SQL commands on occasion.

As you can imagine though, multiple threads calling SQL commands at the same time won't fire because another thread has already opened the connection.

[image: example]

I've a vague idea on how I plan to approach this but I've never had much confidence in myself so a second opinion would really go a long way.

My plan for this is to create a thread for cycling through a list of queued SQL commands.

On handling network data, clients first subscribe to the event of the command being called, doing so they also pass a delegate which will be invoked to signify the events end. 
This delegate is passed the data returned by the sql command.
They then queue the command to be called and pass parameter data for the SQL command.

I've packed all my SQL commands into a class like this.

```
    public static void SetEntityCoodinates( int x, int y, int ID )
    {
        SQLReader.RunQuery( string.Format( @"UPDATE entities SET CellPosX = {0}, CellPosY = {1} WHERE entities.ID = {2};", x, y, ID )
                          , SQLReader.Stream.INPUT
                          , null
                          );
    }
```

Apparently I might have left myself open to SQL Injection but I'd like to tackle one problem at a time.

Mock-up. Sorry for the full-class post, I'll try to break it down.
HandleNetworkData (which is called by the client thread) first subscribes to the the SQLThread by passing an enum type of command, and a delegate to fire when the SQLThread processes the event. In retrospect there isn't much to say beside that.
I could substitute lists for queues but everything else is pretty straight forward I think. I hope.
Not fond of the switch statement though, very ugly.

Please let me know if you think I'm making a mountain out of a molehill and if there's some simple solution I'm not seeing. Any feedback at all would be a greatly appreciated.

```
class SQLThread
{
    public static Dictionary<CommonSQL.Commands, Action<object[]>> m_eventHandler = new Dictionary<CommonSQL.Commands, Action<object[]>>();

    private static List<CommonSQL.Commands> m_executingEvents = new List<CommonSQL.Commands>();
    private static List<object[]> m_executingData = new List<object[]>();

    private static List<CommonSQL.Commands> m_queuedEvents = new List<CommonSQL.Commands>();
    private static List<object[]> m_queuedData = new List<object[]>();

    private static System.Object m_queueLock = new System.Object();

    public static void AddEvent( CommonSQL.Commands packet, Action<object[]> e)
    {
        m_eventHandler.Add( packet, e );
    }
    public static void RemoveEvent(CommonSQL.Commands packet)
    {
        m_eventHandler.Remove(packet);
    }
    public static void QueueEvent( CommonSQL.Commands action, object[] sender )
    {
        lock ( m_queueLock )
        {
            m_queuedEvents.Add( action );
            m_queuedData.Add( sender );
        }
    }
    private static void MoveQueuedEventsToExecuting()
    {
        lock ( m_queueLock )
        {
            while ( m_queuedEvents.Count > 0 )
            {
                CommonSQL.Commands e = m_queuedEvents[0];
                object[] data = m_queuedData[0];

                m_executingEvents.Add( e );
                m_executingData.Add( data );

                m_queuedEvents.RemoveAt( 0 );
                m_queuedData.RemoveAt( 0 );

            }
        }
    }
    public void Update()
    {
        MoveQueuedEventsToExecuting();

        while ( m_executingEvents.Count > 0 )
        {
            CommonSQL.Commands action = m_executingEvents[0];
            object[] data = m_executingData[0];

            m_executingEvents.RemoveAt( 0 );
            m_executingData.RemoveAt( 0 );

            if ( m_eventHandler.ContainsKey(action) )
            {
                object[] returnedData = null;

                switch ( action )
                {
                    case CommonSQL.Commands.SetEntityCoordinates:
                        returnedData = CommonSQL.SetEntityCoodinates( parameterData );
                        break;
                    case CommonSQL.Commands.GetMapData:
                        returnedData = CommonSQL.GetMapData( parameterData );
                        break;
                    case CommonSQL.Commands.GetEntityCoordinates:
                        returnedData = CommonSQL.GetEntityCoordinates( parameterData );
                        break;
                    case CommonSQL.Commands.GetEntityID:
                        returnedData = CommonSQL.GetEntityID( parameterData );
                        break;
                    case CommonSQL.Commands.GetPlayerIDAndPassword:
                        returnedData = CommonSQL.GetPlayerIDAndPassword( parameterData );
                        break;
                    case CommonSQL.Commands.CreateAccount:
                        returnedData = CommonSQL.CreateAccount( parameterData );
                        break;
                    case CommonSQL.Commands.CreateEntity:
                        returnedData = CommonSQL.CreateEntity( parameterData );
                        break;
                }

                m_eventHandler[action].Invoke( returnedData );
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine( string.Format( "No instruction for {0}.", action ) );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually SQL vendors support multiple connections at a time (for sure MS SQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL do support). So would parallel connections be an option? E.g. to open a new connection per each client's request then close it, or take a connection from connections-pool

Comment: Ooh! I will look into that now. That sounds excellent!

Comment: I was struggling to figure out a way I could make it work with parallel connections. Ended up pooling a few connections. A cosy fix but I don't imagine it'll handle too well vs hundreds of clients. Not that I ever expect to get that many. Cheers @Renat